# How to join a slice []interface{} into a string?

Tags: string, go, slice

Is there a stdlib equivalent of this method?

```
func Join(sep string, values ...interface{}) string {
    strs := make([]string, len(values))
    for i, v := range values {
        strs[i] = fmt.Sprintf("%s", v)
    }
    return strings.Join(strs, sep)
}
```

The [`strings`](https://godoc.org/strings) package has a `Join` method, but it only joins a string slice.  I feel like the fmt package could have something like this, I don't know all the % variables that exist.

Comment: Such a function would rarely be of any use. If they put that in the Standard Library, I'd be forced to switch to PHP.

Comment: "I don't know all the % variables that exist." The are all documented in the fmt package. No need to know them if you can look them up.

Comment: @Flimzy , well, there is not need for the `strings.Join` one if you can have a generalized variant that behaves exactly the same when used with strings only.

Comment: @StevenRoose: How `Join` works on a string is plainly defined and obvious. How it works on an `interface{}` is anything but.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there an stdlib equivalent of this method?

No there is not.

Answer (score 1):

```
func StrConvert(a ...interface{}) string {
    str := ""

    for index := 0; index < len(a); index++ {
        str1 := fmt.Sprintf("%v", a[index])
        str += " " + str1
    }
    return str
}
```

you can pass []interface to above function and it will return a string as a response.

Comment: Code only answers are considered low-quality posts. Please add some explanation for your code

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of this question being asked in 2017 (2021 as of writing), it seems this answer cannot be found anywhere, and this post is the top result on Google for "join interface{} slice golang", so I thought I would answer. The solution is actually quite simple and works as expected.

```
joined := strings.Trim(strings.Join(strings.Fields(fmt.Sprint(slice)), ","), "[]")
```

Where `slice` is a variable of type `[]interface{}`. Of course you can use other strings besides `,` as the seperator.

Comment: This won't work correctly if items in `slice` contain strings with spaces as it would put `,` between each word.

Comment: Yep, it's best to use a string builder if you're joining a slice of `any`. I don't think there's a solution besides that that works 100%.